# iOS 10.3 and Audi, Bluetooth audio no longer works. Anyone else?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, ios, car-integration

Since updating to iOS 10.3 the Bluetooth audio on my iPhone 6s no longer works with my Audi (2014 RS4).  The phone calls still work, but no audio apps work - they appear to play and the meta-data appears on the car screen, but just silence.  Most frustrating.

Does anyone else have this issue?  I would like to check before I send a bug report to Apple, so I can see if I can narrow-down any causal factors.

(it looks as if at least one other person is having this issue) http://www.audizine.com/forum/showthread.php/758173-iOS-10-3-problem-with-media-as-input

My Audi MMI version is HN+_EU_AU3G_P0767

Thanks

Comment: This could be an issue with the Car's compliance to Apple CarPlay, and Apple's new APFS may not be supported by your car. Check with the Manufacurer, and Apple to get an amiable solution.

Comment: It's not CarPlay, just vanilla Bluetooth but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

Well, Aren't I a fool! It seems that the iOS update for some reason decided to reset the system volume to zero (but only when connected to that Bluetooth device).

The apps that I used to test didn't have the volume slider visible on screen and the car volume controls don't 'pass-through' so it only appeared silent.

Adjusting the iPhone system volume via the physical buttons on the phone brought the audio back....